# Using String's c_str() and assigning to char const*: assignment of read-only location

Tags: c++, c-strings, c-str

My problem is this: 
I have a constant pointer to a constant char pointer (2D char array where both dimensions are `const`). I need to assign C-strings to this array. I have a `std::vector` of `std::string`s which I used `c_str()` on to create a vector of c_strings. Now I'm assigning those C-string pointers to this array, but I'm getting

```
src/rshell.cpp:45:44: error: assignment of read-only location ‘*(c_arr 
((sizetype)(((long unsigned int)i) * 8ul)))’
for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++) c_arr[i] = commands.at(i);
```

Here's the code with the error

```
/* Confusing as heck, let me explain!
 * char const* means pointer to a constant char
 * so char const* const means a const pointer to a const char
 * and char const* const* means a const pointer to a const char pointer!
 * (Read declarations from right to left to make it make sense -
 *  char const* = POINTER (*) to a CONST CHAR)
 */
char const* const* c_arr = new char*[size1];
for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++)
  c_arr[i] = commands.at(i); // line 38
```

And here's the vector of string to C-string part if it helps.

```
for (tokenizer::iterator it = parse.begin(); it != parse.end(); it++)
  words.push_back(*it);

vector<const char*> commands;
// add string to c_string equiv return vector
for (vector<string>::iterator it = words.begin(); it != words.end(); it++) {
    commands.push_back(it->c_str());
}
```

Comment: You know `c_str` only provides access to the internal buffer of a `string`, which is destroyed on re-allocation or destruction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `commands` is a `std::vector<const char *>`, the expression `&commands[0]` will yield a `const char **` (also known as `char const **`) which you can happily assign to a `char const * const *`. So unless you really need a copy, you could go with

```
char const * const *c_arr = &commands[0];
```

Note that this means that `c_arr` is really only useful as long as `commands` exists (which in turn is really only useful as long as the `std::string` objects in `words` exist).

Comment: I've got a class preserving the strings until they're not needed. I think this will work. Thanks!